# How to avoid scrollbar stacking

Tags: html, css

I have 2 scrollbars in a HTML file. Scrollbar a is short, and scrollbar b is larger. When scrolling in Scrollbar a reaches the end, scrollbar b takes the focus and starts scrolling. How can I avoid this effect? I want when I have the mouse over a scrollbar only to be handled by that scrollbar a, not the b.

```js
document.getElementById('left').onmousewheel = function(e, d) { 
   if((this.scrollTop === (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight) && d < 0)
    || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; margin: 0; }

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1px;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 20vw;
  height: 200vh;
  background: yellow; 
}

.static {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

#left {
  width: 20vw;  
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

#middle {
  height: calc(100vh - 15px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="left">  
    <div id="middle">
      <h2>Left</h2>
      <p style="height: 9001px;">Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="scroll">
    <h2>Right</h2>
    <p style="height: 300px;">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

When you scroll in `left`, keep the mouse on `left` and then start scrolling again `right` will start scrolling. I'm trying to guess if this could be done only using CSS as I'm trying to avoid Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent scrolling of parent event when position of inner element scroll reaches the bottom.

```
document.getElementById('left').onmousewheel = function(e, d) { 
   if((this.scrollTop === (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight) && d < 0)
    || (this.scrollTop === 0 && d > 0)) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

or you can add below CSS

```
section {  
 overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I just updated the code-snippet with this javascript code and didn't work properly.